# How to use repro to modify sip request?

Tags: asterisk

I am using the **repro sip proxy** to modify SIP requests.

I need to change my SIP request header from 7001 to 7001_abc.

How could I do this using repro sip proxy with **asterisk**?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that you want to change to person you are dialing to from "7001" to "7001_abc", prior to the call entering the Asterisk dialplan?

If that is the case, you don't really need "repro" in order to do this. You can simply to the following in your Asterisk server:

```
file: sip.conf

[myprovider]
type=peer
host=bla.bla.bla
context=from_provider
.
.
```

Now, in dialplan you can do the following:

```
file: extensions.conf

[from_provider]
exten => _X.,1,Noop(*** Retargetting ***)
 same =>     n,Dial(Local/${EXTEN}_abc@my_dialplan)
 same =>     n,Hangup

[my_dialplan]
exten => _XXXX_abc,1,Noop(*** Start my thing ***)
```

Just as a closed caption, it's more common to use a prefix, not a suffix. In addition, I would use Kamailio and not Repro, as the information and scalability of it is much better.

Comment: Not sure I follow you comment from below - I guess either your scenario is not complete or I'm missing something. Can you please detail the complete scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am doing 7001 to create unique user id, where user has to provision its deskphone/softphone.
Now I want user to provision 7001@companyname.com our proxy will change it to 7001_companyname or 4535342@pbx.sip.com (any random unique number)